# webpack dev middleware, how to autoreload when HMR fails

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am getting the following message in my browser's console when I change my javascript source:

> [HMR] The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (Full reload
>   needed) This is usually because the modules which have changed (and
>   their parents) do not know how to hot reload themselves. See
>   http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html
>   for more details.

My question is how can I tell webpack to just auto reload the page when this happens?

Here is my server set up:

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));

        // Disable views cache
        app.set('view cache', false);

        var webpack = require('webpack');

        var webpackConfig = require('../client/webpack.config');
        var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

        app.use(require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
            noInfo: true, publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
        }));
        app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));
```

and my webpack.config:

```
var path = require('path');
var AureliaWebpackPlugin = require('../node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('../node_modules/webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: [
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
            './client/src/main'
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            breeze: 'breeze-client/build/breeze.debug',
            resources: path.resolve( __dirname, 'src', 'resources'),
            utils: path.resolve( __dirname, 'src', 'resources', 'utils', 'utils'),
            tradestudyUtils: path.resolve( __dirname, 'src', 'resources', 'tradestudy-utils', 'tradestudy-utils')
        }
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new AureliaWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        //preLoaders: [
        //    {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'eslint-loader'}
        //],
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'] },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/, query: { presets: ['es2015-loose', 'stage-1'], plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'] } },
            { test: /\.css?$/, loader: 'style!css' },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
            { test: /\.(png|gif|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' },
            { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff2' },
            { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff' },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file-loader' }
        ]
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass [parameter](https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware#config) `reload` to `webpack-hot-middleware/client`:

```
    entry: {
        main: [
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
            './client/src/main'
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Does this refresh the entire page or is it indeed "hot module replacement"?

Comment: I had a slightly different setup, but I added the 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true' before aurelia-bootstrapper in entry and it was hot module replacement